# Show that $G = \{gx | x \in G\}$

Tags: group-theory

Let (G, *) be a group and let $g \in G$ be some fixed element in G.

Show that $G = \{gx | x \in G\}$

Case 1 : Let G be finite

let $b \in G $. Then

Consider set ${gx,gx^2,gx^3,...}$

Since G is infinite set, so elements in above set will have repetition. So $gx^i=gx^j$ for some i,j. So $g^{1-j}=e$. $g^k=e$.

Now $b=be=bg^k$, so $G\subseteq \{gx | x \in G\}$.

Let $gx$ be any element. so $gx \in G$ (closure property).

Is this proof correct ? And how to do when G is infinite set

Thanks

Comment: For any $h\in G$, $x:=g^{-1}h$ has $gx=h$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to split into cases. For $b\in G$, write $b=g(g^{-1}b)$.

Comment: if i make cases then how to do?

Comment: @SophieClad Just write the same thing twice I guess. Because for this problem there is no difference between the finite and infinite cases. Well, ok, in the finite case you make define a map $f:G\to G$ by $f(x)=gx$, show it is injective, and then conclude that it is surjective by finiteness of $G$. But it would be much easier just to show directly that $f$ is surjective (which is pretty much what I did in my answer), which holds in the infinite case as well.

Comment: thanks a lot....